# My button is not appearing on my Tkinter project

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Why isn't my button showing up on my Tkinter project?

```
def mainMenu():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Main Menu")
    window.geometry("400x400")
    window.rowconfigure(0, minsize=200, weight=1)
    window.columnconfigure(1, minsize=200, weight=1)
    
    buttonsFrame = tk.Frame(master=window)
    
    POSBtn = tk.Button(master=buttonsFrame, text="POS", bg="red")
    POSBtn.place(x=200,y=200, width=250,height=250)


    buttonsFrame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")
    window.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainMenu()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your grid, try this:

Change `window.columnconfigure(1, minsize=200, weight=1)` to `window.columnconfigure(0, minsize=200, weight=1)`

or if you need columnconfigure as 1 then

Change `buttonsFrame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")` to `buttonsFrame.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="nsew")`